# Can't browse any website on IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, windows-server-2008

I've just installed IIS on windows server 2008 R2. I left everything as default while installing. After installation however, I'm not able to browse any of the websites added. Even the default web site is not browsable. When i right click the Default web site then click Manage web site and the Browse nothing changes.

Comment: can you tell what is the error you are getting in the browser?By browsing do you mean by directory browsing?

Comment: The thing is İ do not get any kind of warning or and error. It just keeps silent. When I browse it shoud open up the web site in the internet explorer. But it does not.I mean if I type http:/localhost/MyWebSite it does nothe display my home page.

Answer (score 1):

When you type http://localhost/ what exactly do you receive?

You should either be receiving a "Welcome to IIS" page or page denied.